# React-router-dom specificity navlink and pseudo-class

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have an issue with the specifity of the active class from `NavLink` (`.chooser--active`) and a pseudoclass (`a:visited`) on the `a` element.

[image => firefox dev-tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbljJ.png)

The Stylesheet Vita.scss (where  `.chooser--active` is defineded) is imported in a lower component than app.scss (where `a:visited`is defined).

I try to avoid `!important` - any help is welcome.

*edit:*

```
/*_root.scss*/
:root {
--black: rgb(0, 0, 0);
--blue: rgb(16, 29, 141);
}

/*
App.scss (import in parent)

@import "./root";
*/

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--blue);
    &:hover {
        text-decoration: underline 3px var(--blue);
    }

    &:active,
    &:visited {
        color: var(--blue);
    }
}


/*Vita.scss*/

.chooser {
 &--active {
        text-decoration: 3px underline var(--black);
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 1.1em;
        color: black;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bump the specificity in your file, i.e. `.chooser--active.chooser--active`? Can you include in your question all relevant code, i.e. your styles?

Comment: @DrewReese  thank you - bumping the specifity worked for me.